# A problem on the existence of bijections

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $ A_i, i = 1, 2, \cdots, n $ be finite sets of the same size. For all $ i = 1, 2, \cdots, n $, let $ f_i: A_i \to A_1 $ be a bijective function, where $ f_1 $ is an identity function. Suppose that the functions satisfy the following property, for all $ i = 1, 2, \cdots, n $ and $ j = 1, 2, \cdots, n $:

$$ \forall x \in A_i \cap A_j, f_i(x) = f_j(x). $$

Given the sets $ A_i, i = 1, 2, \cdots, n $, is it always possible to find the bijections $ f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_n $, which satisfy the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $A_1=\{0,1\}$, $A_2=\{0,2\}$ and $A_3=\{0,3\}$.

Then the functions $f_i$ are determined for $i=1,2,3$ with $f_2(2)=f_3(3)=1$.

Now let $A_4=\{2,3\}$.

Then $f_4(2)=f_2(2)=1$ and $f_4(3)=f_3(3)=1$ according to the demands.

But then $f_4$ is not injective.

---

edit (counterexample for $n=3$)

Let $A_1=\{0,1,2\}$, $A_2=\{0,1,3\}$ and $A_3=\{0,2,3\}$.

Then $f_2(0)=0$, $f_2(1)=1$ and $f_2(3)=2$ according to the demands.

But also $f_3(3)=f_2(3)=2$ and $f_3(2)=2$ is demanded so $f_3$ is not injective.

Comment: What if $ n = 3 $?

Comment: I have added a counterexample for $n=3$.